# Passing a union as one of two arguments in a macro

Tags: c

I'm trying to define a generic/macro function that sets a property of a union i've defined. I've worked with macros before, but never tried to pass multiple arguments. In this case I got a union which represents a variable (Nothing really interesting) and I want to have a single set function that allows me to set the correct property of the union's instance without specifying the datatype. This is my code:

```c
// represents a variable
union Var {
  float f;
  char *s;
  bool b;
  // 'f' 's' or 'b'
  char type;
};

// setter
void set_int(union Var *var, int newval) { var->f = (float)newval; var->type = 'f'; }
void set_float(union Var *var, float newval) { var->f = newval; var->type = 'f'; }
void set_char(union Var *var, char newval) { var->s = (char[2]){newval, 0}; var->type = 's'; }
void set_string(union Var *var, char *newval) { var->s = newval; var->type = 's'; }
void set_bool(union Var *var, bool newval) { var->b = newval; var->type = 'b'; }
#define set(VAR, X) \
  _Generic((X), \
    int: set_int(union Var, X), \
    float: set_float(union Var), \
    char: set_char(union Var), \
    char *: set_string(union Var), \
    bool: set_bool(union Var))(X)

int main(void) {
    union Var myvar;

    // myvar.f = 1.5; myvar.type = 'f'; works, but i want to do this instead:
    set(&myvar, 1.5);

    return 0;
}
```

the output that i'm getting:

```
var.c: In function ‘main’:
var.c:92:18: error: expected expression before ‘union’
     int: set_int(union Var, X), \
                  ^~~~~
var.c:117:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘set’
     set(&myvar, 1.5);
     ^~~
var.c:92:10: error: too few arguments to function ‘set_int’
     int: set_int(union Var, X), \
          ^~~~~~~
var.c:117:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘set’
     set(&myvar, 1.5);
     ^~~
var.c:85:6: note: declared here
 void set_int(union Var *var, int newval) { var->f = newval; var->type = 'f'; }
      ^~~~~~~
```

I'm getting desparate, so any help would be appreciated a lot!

PS: I'm not great at C at all, so don't burn me down if I'm making a stupid mistake. :)

Comment: Unrelated, but your `set_int` is setting wrong values.

Comment: I see. Must've looked over it. Thanks!

Comment: Replace the `union Var` with `VAR` in your Generic expansion.

Comment: I wouldn't use a `union` inside a macro to implement "generic" types. See my recent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621027/writing-a-generic-struct-print-method-in-c/65621483#65621483 It shows/discusses the various ways to do what you're trying to do: switch on type, virtual function table, etc. and ways to organize the structs.

Comment: I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Your `type` element of the union cannot be used to decide which other type is stored in the union.  You need something like `struct TagName { char type; union Var { float f; char *s; bool b; }; };` using an anonymous union.  Now `type` doesn't share the same storage as `f`, `b`, and `s` — so you do have a discriminated union now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your macro is expanding to pass a type name for the first parameter to the function, which is not valid syntax.  You want instead to pass whatever the `VAR` parameter is:

```
#define set(VAR, X) \
  _Generic((X), \
    int: set_int, \
    float: set_float, \
    double: set_float, \
    char: set_char, \
    char *: set_string, \
    bool: set_bool)((VAR), (X))
```

Comment: It seems like that worked somewhat! I still get errors tho: 
```var.c: In function ‘main’:
var.c:91:12: error: ‘_Generic’ selector of type ‘double’ is not compatible with any association
   _Generic((X), \
            ^
var.c:117:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘set’
     set(&myvar, 1.5);
     ^~~
```

Comment: @SjoerdVermeulen Yes, because the constant `1.5` has type `double`.  You can add a case for that.  It would also be a good idea to change the type in the union to `double`.

Comment: I already suspected something as silly as that. It appears to work now! Thanks a bunch! There's still some things to solve but i don't think they're related to the macro thing. If you spot anything wrong with the setters please tell me!