# Using function pointers as part of a linked list

Tags: c, lisp, void-pointers, cons

I am writing a Lisp interpreter and I've decided to store the environment's symbols (true, false, cons, car, cdr, variables etc.) in a linked list, with each "entry" using the same structure used to store lisp atoms (in my code called a "cell").

The following structs and enums are defined:

```c
typedef enum {STRING, FLOAT, SYMBOL, LIST} ctype;
typedef struct { void* data; ctype type; void* next; } cell;
```

I used a `void*` with `data` to point to the atom (or a symbol) so that I didn't have to fiddle with unions. `next` points to the next cell. Since s-expressions can be nested, `data` can also point to a cell, meaning that this implementation could have nested lists.

The following fundamental Lisp functions are defined as such:

```c
cell* cons(cell* car, cell* cdr) { car->next = cdr; return car; }
cell* car(cell* head) { return head; }
cell* cdr(cell* head) { return head->next; }
```

and a function `stnode()` is defined so that the manual memory allocation can be taken care of and cells can quickly be created:

```c
cell* stnode(void* data, ctype type) {
    cell* tmp = malloc(sizeof(cell));
    tmp->data = malloc(sizeof(data));
    tmp->type = type;
    memcpy(tmp->data, data, sizeof(data));
    return tmp;
}
```

Finally, I have the function stdenv, which returns a Linked List of cells containing pointers to functions that I would like to use in my lisp. These are cons(), car() and cdr().

```c
cell* stdenv() {
    return cons(stnode(&cons, SYMBOL), cons(stnode(&car, SYMBOL), stnode(&cdr, SYMBOL))); }
```

There are better recursive ways to achieve the above code, but I'll cross that bridge when I get to it. At this point with so little code it isn't worth adding complexity before I can guarantee the code actually works.

I've tested `stnode()` with strings, booleans, integers and pointers to other structs, which all work fine (with proper void pointer dereferencing in place, of course) but I can't get function pointers to work. The problematic code is `stdenv()`, here's the code I tried to use to test it:

```c
cell* symbols = stdenv();
cell* cd = *(*symbols->data)(symbols);
printf("%p\n", cd->data);
```

...the assumption being that if everything was working as I expected, I should be presented with the memory address in the function (because of how I wrote `stdenv` in this case it should be cons()).

Compiling with GCC on Ubuntu got me the following warnings and errors:

```
lisp.c: In function ‘main’:
lisp.c:26:15: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
   26 |  cell* cd = *(*symbols->data)(symbols);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
lisp.c:26:15: error: called object is not a function or function pointer
   26 |  cell* cd = *(*symbols->data)(symbols);
      |              ~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with the code for stdenv, since I've passed the memory address of each function to `cons()`.

Comment: Your `data` field is clearly not a function pointer. After all, you are also assigning it the pointer to a chunk of memory allocated through `malloc()`. What is your goal when you do `*(*symbols->data)(symbols)`? That does not make much sense unless `symbols->data` is a function pointer (and even then, you would still be dereferencing a `void*` pointer which is invalid).

Comment: `cons(a, b)` is not supposed to modify `a`. It's supposed to create a NEW cell whose car points to `a` and cdr points to `b`.

Comment: See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65621027/writing-a-generic-struct-print-method-in-c/65621483#65621483 It also uses a linked list of heterogeneous objects with virtual function callbacks

Comment: Your `cons()` function is actually `rplacd()`

Comment: `sizeof(data)` in `stnode` is just going to give you the size of a pointer. You need to pass the data size to the function.

Comment: In real Lisp it is not the case that all objects are cells that can point to the next cell. A string or floating point value has no concept of "next object". Only aggregate objects like conses and vectors have fields that contain other values. If you don't spend a few years programming in Lisp first, you will probably reinvent it badly.  The first Lisp was also invented badly; some of the ideas took well over a decade or more to mature.

Comment: Ignoring strings (they complicate things, so I would recommend that you do that at first) but allowing numbers, Lisp essentially consists of three things; atoms, cons cells (i.e. pairs of values), and functions. The atoms are symbols and numbers. Functions are not symbols, and cells are not atoms. Lists are, perhaps surprisingly, not fundamental.