# How to have a function pointer type that takes an arbitrary pointer as argument?

Tags: c, types, preprocessor

I have a function that applies a function of type `apply_fn` to each element of a list, and a macro that will declare a temporary function an pass it to `list_apply`:

```c
typedef void apply_fn( void * );

void list_apply( t_list *lst, apply_fn *apply );

# define list_apply( lst, apply_fn_body ) \
  do {\
    void _l_function_ apply_fn_body\
    list_apply(lst, _l_function_);\
  while (0)
```

I use this macro to simulate an anonymous function (like in js) so I can call my function like this for example:

```c
list_apply(&my_list, (void * elem) {
  // do something with the element
});
```

So everything works fine until this point (with `gcc`), but I want to be able to call my function like this for example:

```c
list_apply(&my_list, (int * elem) {
  // do something with element as an integer
});
```

I know that I can define my function type like this:

```c
typedef void apply_fn();
```

And it works fine then but if for example I do this:

```c
list_apply(&my_list, ( void ) {
  // function that takes no parameter instead of one pointer
});
```

I want it to still throw a compilation error instead of undefined behavior, what I'd like to be able to do is:

```c
typedef void apply_fn( any_type * );
```

That's of course not possible but are there some alternatives that would do the same ?

Comment: Can't you provide the type as a third argument? Did you try to use GCC's extension `typeof`? Or `_Generic`? Remember, the preprocessor is a quite simple search-and-replace tool and has no insight into C syntax or C semantic.

Comment: Are interested only in GCC or in standard C? What is the declaration of `list_apply` function? Are you expecting `list_apply` function to change declaration depending on type? `_L_function_` identifiers starting with `_` followed by upper case letters are reserved. Do not use them in your code.

Comment: How about keeping the parameter type as `void *` and casting it inside the function body as appropriate?

Comment: Generating functions with macros is a very bad idea. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this?

Comment: See my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) as it may help with your understanding if not your problem.

Comment: @KamilCuk list_apply stays the same, the macro just generates the function that is passed to it through a function pointer

Comment: `list_apply stays the same` Then passing `void (int*)`  to a function that calls that function via `void (void*)` is invalid.

Comment: @KamilCuk _ followed by uppercase is reserved only in c++ not in c

Comment: `_` followed by uppercase is reserved both in C++ and in C. C11 standard https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3 -> `All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use.`

Comment: Is using C++ an option?

Comment: Maybe `__typeof__` will help?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat i'm writing a c library

Comment: Note that this code uses "nested function" which is GCC-only extension.

Comment: What about doing it the Linux-Kernel-Way. Make a `for` loop in the macro that iterates over the list and applied the body of the loop to each element. Like `LIST_FOR_EACH(&my_list, int *elem) { ... do things with `elem` ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this solution is limited only to GCC world.

You  need two nested functions. One that processes `any_type*` and a wrapper that maps it from `void*`. Finally, pass the wrapper to `list_apply()`.

You need something that expands this code:

```
list_apply(&my_list, (int * elem) { *elem = 42; });
```

to this:

```
do {
    void _l_function_(int * elem) { *elem = 42; }
    void _l_wrapper_(void* elem) { _l_function_(elem); }
    list_apply(lst, _l_wrapper_);
}  while (0)
```

The possible macro could be:

```
# define list_apply( lst, type, apply_fn_body )          \
  do {                                                   \
    void _l_function_ apply_fn_body                      \
    void _l_wrapper_(void* elem) { _l_function_(elem); } \
    list_apply(&lst, _l_wrapper_);                       \
  } while (0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do that:

First instead of `typedef void apply_fn( void * );` I wrote `typedef void apply_fn();`.

Then to throw an error if parameters are invalid I had to add an argument to my macro: I pass the type that we want to it and I cast the nested function to a function pointer which has the right type and number of arguments like this:

```c
# define list_apply( lst, type, apply_fn_body ) \
  do {\
    void _l_function_ apply_fn_body\
    void (*_checker_)( type * ptr ) = _l_function_;\
    list_apply(&lst, _l_function_);\
  } while (0)
```

Comment: Sorry but this approach changes the signature of the original `list_apply` function.

Comment: @tstanisl no because I pass a `apply_fn*` (which is `void (*)()`) so the parameters are arbitrary, and since it takes a `apply_fn*` it's valid