# Is there a way to point to a struct member from a function pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm doing a double linked list from scratch in C and was programming the iter(able) function.
However my struct has a bunch of fields and I don't necessarily want to mess with all when I call the function. I want to choose what member to alter in the function call.

```
typedef struct s_command 
{
    int         argc;               
    char        *argv[MAXARGS];     
    t_token     *args;               
    char        **envp;             
    t_builtin   builtin;            
    void        *input;             
    void        *output;
    struct s_command        *next;
    struct s_command        *prev;
}           t_command;
```

My obvious choice was having an int argument that gets caught by an if else (can't use switch) to pick what field I want.
As such:

```
void    dll_iter(t_command *lst, int property, void (*f)(void *))
{
    if (!lst || !property || !f)
        return ;
    while (lst)
    {
        if(property == 1)
            f(lst->argc);
        else if(property == 2)
            f(lst->argv);
        else if(property == 3)
            f(lst->args);
        ...
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}
```

But I can't stop but wonder if C has any way to simplify this. Make it cleaner.
What I would really like was someting like:

```
void    dll_iter(t_command *lst, void (*f)(void *))
```

where `f` would call directly the member it wants.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Why can't you use a switch?

Comment: Can't you just pass the node pointer itself? If the function is meant to choose... let it?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: Abstracted iterators are a thing. I don't understand his rationale but the answer is instructive.

Comment: @Joshua - Overengineering is a thing too.

Comment: @Nelfeal because my school doesn't allow it. Along with a 25 line limit per function and 4 arguments per function. I would prefer to use it. But I'll automatically fail on the assignment if i do.

Comment: @MiguelP: Bad school. Shrug.

Comment: @Joshua we have a bunch of stupid rules IMO. They say that they "have a reason" but I've tried to ask around and the only good reason so far is so freshmen don't write unmaintainable spaghetti code. There's zero reason for other more advanced students. I can share the rules if you want.

Comment: "where `f` would call directly the member it wants" - either `dll_iter` needs to know what member `f` wants (and so you need a `property` parameter or similar), or `f` needs to know and you must pass it the node pointer, as StoryTeller points out.

Comment: *"I can't stop but wonder if C has any way to simplify this. Make it cleaner"* - yeah, that's what `switch` is there for. Man I would love to talk to some of these professors handing out nonsensical homework like this :')

Comment: See my answer about generic struct printing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650 I believe it has a lot of what you want.

Comment: There is an obvious problem with your approach: `f(lst->argc)` and `f(lst->argv)` pass different types. It is impossible to define a function `f` that would be callable in both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how this will go over with a school, because this relies on border-line language-lawyering. But if you want a generic iterating function, just abstract away the only thing that matters to it, the links.

```
struct link {
    struct link *next;
    struct link *prev;
};

struct command {
    struct link link;
    // other members...
};
```

And now you can write

```
dll_iter(struct link*, void (*f)(struct link*));
```

Because a pointer to structure shares an address with it's first member, `f` can convert internally to the concrete node type it cares about. Meanwhile, the iteration function only deals with (and knows of) the members it needs to implement iteration.

Just note the calling the function is a little different now

```
void access_fn(struct link* link_p) {
    struct command *cmd = (struct command*)link_p;
    // do stuff
}

// ...

dll_iter(&cmd->link, access_fn);
```

Heck, now the function can even access more than one member at a time. How's that for flexibility?

Comment: I too will be glad if this ends up being the answer, but only OP can confirm if he can do this.

Comment: I thought about doing something kind of similar. Having a dll with the links and a `void *content`where I would put a struct. However last time I did that I burnt a lot of space  (limit of 80 chars and 25 lines per function) doing it because of type casting `((t_content *)lst->content)->memberN = ((t_content *)node->content)->memberN`. I think this could be an interesting alternative. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

It can be done. Time for stacking function pointers. We're getting really close to higher order functions now.

```
void dll_iter(t_command *lst, void *(*decoder)(t_command *entry), void (*f)(void *argpointer))
{
    if (!lst || !decoder || !f)
        return ;
    while (lst)
    {
        f(decoder(lst));
        lst = lst->next;
    }
}

void *decoder_argc(t_command *entry) { return &entry->argc; }
void *decoder_argv(t_command *entry) { return &entry->argv; }
//...
```

Note that `f` always receives a pointer to the struct member.

Invocation looks like:

```
   dll_iter(list, decoder_argc, f); // Process argc for all entries in list
   dll_iter(list, decoder_argv, f); // ditto for argv
```

Comment: Have you... tried your code? You call `dll_iter` with 3 arguments yet it has 2 parameters, and you call `decoder` with 1 yet it has 2.

Comment: @Nelfeal: Ah missing ) after argument decoder.

Comment: Ok, now `f` needs to be of the form `void f(void*)` unless you allow incompatible pointer types (compiler warning), so it needs to cast the argument to use it. I don't see the advantage over doing `lst->argc` in `dll_iter` or passing `lst` to `f` and doing `lst->argc` there.

Comment: @Nelfeal: I kind of wish I knew what was in f.

Comment: @Joshua `f` is just a function that I might program latter to go through one of each node member

Comment: @MiguelP Because it's a more complicated way of doing a switch inside `dll_iter`. It's basically moving the selection from a very simple and understandable switch to a group of "decoder" functions. It provides no benefit.

Comment: This is basically the same as passing different `f` functions... just more complicated for no reason.

Comment: @MiguelP: To start with, the dropped `)` (I'm prone to dropped characters when typing) caused `Nelfeal` to misread it. After that; well I think the readers see how this is awkward and don't see past it to see how it can't be better without throwing away the whole idea. I can't imagine an `f` for which this makes sense. It's almost like there's a host of different `f` functions.

Comment: @Joshua *" It's almost like there's a host of different f functions"* - you nailed it. Cannot define a single `f` that would be able to handle all of those different types.