# Redefine pointer to struct

Tags: c

I am wondering if it is possible to redefine the type of a pointer as in the code below. The purpose is to avoid two long for loops which would be identical but just iterate over separate struct types (output_t vs. special_t).

```
typedef struct output {
    unsigned short control_type;
    many other random fields;
} output_t;
typedef struct special {
    unsigned short control_type;
    many other fields;
} special_t;

output_t * ot = start of memory segment
for (j = 0; j < normal_count + special_count; j++, ot++) {
    if (j == normal_count) {
        redefine ot as pointing to beginning of a segment of struct special_t
    }
    switch (ot->control_type) {
    case 1:
        generate_result(ot, memoryA);
        break;
    case 2:
        generate_result(ot, memoryB);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Put the long identical code in a function, and call it from both loops.

Comment: Post a real [mcve] (the one with "identical codes"). It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: You can't change the type of a variable dynamically in C.

Comment: It's a little dicey, but _if_ you truly have an array of `output_t` followed by one of `special_t`, I think you can do this in _two_ loops: `output_t *ot = start of memory segment; for (j = 0; j < normal_count; j++, ot++) generate_result_ot(ot);  special_t *st = (special_t *) ot; for (j = 0; j < special_count; j++, st++) generate_result_st(st);`

Comment: The compiler needs to know the size of the struct a pointer points to in order to use pointer arithmetic (like incrementing the pointer.) If your two structs differ, then you cannot successfully cast the pointer variable from one to the other.

Comment: If you can have a common type element, you may benefit from my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650)

Comment: You seem to want templates and/or inheritance. Both are supported in C++. Neither comes naturally in C. You can get templates by abusing the preprocessor. And you can get inheritance if you disable strict aliasing optimizations. But without seeing the actual code that you're trying to improve, the best course of action cannot be known.

Comment: I have expanded my code to be more clear on the situation, it's primarily about choosing the destination to generate the result to. However, it appears that what I want is not possible, at least in the way my question asks.

Comment: From what you've posted so far, it looks like a `union` could be used.  X Windows has used [such a `union` for events for decades](https://linux.die.net/man/3/xevent)  Also, not that identifiers that end in `_t` are reserved by POSIX, so if you're targeting a POSIX system such as Linux, you're risking collisions.

Comment: If you _could_ redefine `ot` to be of another type (which you can't) you'd have a problem with `generate_result`, unless you use `_Generic`s. Why not call `generate_result_normal` or `generate_result_special` and cast `ot` to the pointer type you need it to be?

Comment: @CraigEstey thanks your void pointer solution is definitely something that could work. The only issue is with pointer incrementation, but I can increment that in separate for loops without wasting 60 lines.

Comment: @TedLyngmo indeed, but a void pointer argument for ot in generate_result would take care of that issue.

Comment: Sure, you could cast inside the function if you'd rather do that. The `switch` in the function you show seems to be enough though. Why check the type twice? Like @AndrewHenle suggested, a `union` could help `struct foo { unsigned short control_type; union { output_t o; special_t s; }; };`

Comment: Yes, that is a bit more confusing to get the hang of but it could work. So much interesting solutions