# Memory allocation for different type of singly list nodes in C

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, singly-linked-list

I am in the process of building a linked list for later use.
Basic singly direction list, defined like so:

```
typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *content;
} first_type;

typedef struct {
    char *name;
    char *content;
} second_type;

typedef union {
    first_type first;
    second_type second;
} table_data;

typedef struct node {
    int table_type;
    table_data table;
    struct node *next_node;
} list_node;

typedef struct {
    list_node *head_node;
}linked_list;
```

Few notes:

1. The structs first_type/second_type might contain more strings and probably different amount of strings from each other.
2. Strings in first_type/second_type has unknown amount of characters and should be dynamically allocated.
3. The code above + relevant header stuff defined in **list.h** and the list functions in **list.c**.
4. Main function call different programs that uses this linked list functions

Questions:

1. Where should I allocate the memory for the nodes and their values? (**list.c**? on each calling program?)
2. How can I keep dynamic memory allocation when:

- Each node can hold one of the union types (AKA different size of memory to allocate).
- Each string on first_type/second_type can contain unlimited lenght strings.

This is my first stack overflow post, so, sorry for the mess.
If more information need to be provided, please let me know.
Thanks!

Comment: allocate memory for a node when you need it. i.e. when you have data that you want to add to the list.  when you write the function to create a node, also write the function to delete a node.

Comment: *"Each node can hold one of the union types (AKA different size of memory to allocate)."* strikes me as a misunderstanding of what a [union](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/union) is. There are no union type*s* (plural) in this example, as there is just one union - which contains a number of members. The size of a union will be at least the size of its largest member (possible trailing padding). That is, `sizeof (table_data)` is constant - its allocation requirement does not change, even if the allocated object is only ever accessed through a single member.

Comment: My answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) may be of some help. It even has a linked list impl.