# How is filter function working for different types of pointers?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, function-pointers

**Writing a filter function that can handle different types of arrays in C!**

I tried to write a filter function that takes an integer array and a callback function that evaluates to true or false. Based on the result of the callback function, an element is added to the filtered array, and the function returns the filtered array. Can we generalize it? Like, can we make it work for any type of array? I am not able to figure out how to make it work for strings (char *'s).

Here's is the code snippet, could anyone please explain how's working? (flow and what's being passed for both integer array and char * arrays).
What's `memcpy` copying in case of char * arrays?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *filter(void *array, int size, int elementSize, int (*fn)(void *), int *filteredSize);
int isEven(void *);
int startsWith(void *);

void main()
{
    int arr[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}, *evens;
    char *strs[5] = {"Boy", "Apple", "Cat", "Zebra", "Aeroplane"};
    char **fStrs;
    int n, i;
    evens = (int *)filter(arr, 8, sizeof(int), isEven, &n);
    puts("Evens");
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", evens[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(evens);

    fStrs = (char **)filter(strs, 5, sizeof(char *), startsWith, &n);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%s  ", fStrs[i]);
    printf("\n");
    free(fStrs);
}

void *filter(void *array, int size, int elementSize, int (*fn)(void *), int *filteredSize)
{
    int i;
    void *filteredArray;
    *filteredSize = 0;
    filteredArray = malloc(size * elementSize);
    if (filteredArray == NULL)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        void *currentElementLoc = (char *)array + (i * elementSize);
        if ((*fn)(currentElementLoc))
        {
            void *filteredElementLoc = (char *)filteredArray + (*filteredSize * elementSize);
            memcpy(filteredElementLoc, currentElementLoc, elementSize);
            (*filteredSize)++;

        }
    }
    filteredArray = realloc(filteredArray, *filteredSize * elementSize);
    if (filteredArray == NULL)
    {
        free(filteredArray);
        return NULL;
    }

    return filteredArray;
}

int isEven(void *p)
{
    int num = *((int *)p);
    return !(num & 1);
}

int startsWith(void *ptrToStr)
{
    static int hasRun = 0;
    static char ch;
    char *str = *((char **)ptrToStr);
    if (!hasRun)
    {
        puts("Starts with");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        hasRun = 1;
    }
    return *str == ch;
}
```

Comment: I _think_ you're talking about "generic" objects. For some background, see my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650)

Comment: @Aqib Javid Bhat, "how to make it work for strings." --> In C, _string_ is not a type, so why are _strings_ part of a "works for all data types" task?

Comment: What do you mean by "make it work for strings"? Please show a call to `filter` that *doesn't* work.

Comment: @n.m. I was having an issue with dereferencing. I hadn't used char pointer arrays yet, so I was deferencing it the wrong way. 
As character arrays may be of variable length so I didn't know what to pass as element size. 
I broke down the problem info small parts and tried to check what am I passing to the callback function in case of array of char ptrs.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Right! I mean char *'s.
I have working code, Can anyone lemme know what's going on and how's it working for char * arrays and int arrays and others. I've some confusions. I want to make sure my assumptions are right!!

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Please [edit] your question and insert code that you have an issue with.

Comment: Is there anything that *does not* work? If so, how exactly? What are the error messages or unexpected results? If everything works, then what is the problem? If you don't understand how the code works, then the question should be "how does the code work?" and not "is it possible/how to make it work?"

Comment: @n.m. Let me update the question. The actual question was "Is it possible..." and the time I posted it, I didn't know it, I was thinking I won't be possible for strings (I was missing the point - Arrays of strings is actually - Array of char *'s). And it will normally work will char *' s as it works with other types of pointers. I was having issues with dereferencing - like what stores what! I somehow understood it, but not clearly. Lemme change the question to 'How this code works'

Comment: @n.m. How does the code work... Ain't a good question!! This is my first stackoverflow question.

Comment: Pointers are not magical. They are copied exactly like any other data type, byte by byte. The *pointed-to* data is not touched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any experience using [`qsort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/algorithm/qsort)? The *callback* function for `qsort` has the signature `int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)`. Almost all of the same principles of `qsort` apply to your `filter` function.

In both cases, the callback function is being provided pointers to *elements* of the array. These elements may themselves be pointers.

Remember: pointers are values. There is no fundamental difference between copying the value of one `int` to another `int`, and copying the value of one (e.g.) `float *` to another `float *`.

```
int a = 5;
int b = a;
```

```
float some_data = 1.23f;
float *a_pointer = &some_data;
float *b_pointer = a_pointer;
```

Both the [assignments](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) `b = a` and `a_pointer = b_pointer` perform a byte-wise copy of the value of the right to the object on the left.

By extension, `memcpy` works the same way, but through one level of *indirection*.

```
int a = 5;
int b;

memcpy(&b, &a, sizeof (int));
```

```
float some_data = 1.23f;
float *a_pointer = &some_data;
float *b_pointer;

memcpy(&b_pointer, &a_pointer, sizeof (float *));
```

In both examples, the third argument to `memcpy` is the size of the *object* being copied. In the first example, an `int`, in the second example, a `float *`.

`memcpy` requires you specify where in memory these objects exist, hence it accepts two pointers, but it does not care what the objects *are* - just how much memory they occupy.

With

```
char *first_array[2] = {
    "Hello",         
    "World" 
};
char *second_array[2];   
                         
memcpy(&second_array[0], &first_array[1], sizeof (char *));
```

`memcpy` copies the value (just happens to be a pointer value, a `char *`) of the second element of the first array to the first element of the second array.

---

So back to `filter`. There is one caveat shared with `qsort`, and one problem unique to your function.

Like `qsort`, you can operate on arrays of arrays. In these instances, care must be taken by the callback function to correctly specify the type passed via `void *`.

So if you have an array of arrays like

```
char data[][32] = {
    "foo",
    "bar"
};
```

then the callback is actually receiving a `char (*)[32]` - a pointer to an array. This means a callback function cannot be made to work "generically" on all string containers. `char **` and `char (*)[N]` are not equivalent. An "array of strings" is not *always* an array of `char *`.

A unique problem with your `filter` function is that creating a new array that potentially shares data with the previous array opens up a concern of *ownership*, and raises a lot of questions:

- If both arrays contain pointer values returned by `malloc` (or similar) - which array owner is responsible for passing those pointer values to `free`?

  - If its the new array owner, how does the the owner of old array know which values *not* to pass to `free`?
- Should the new array be considered a *view* into the old array?

  - How does the owner of the old array know the new array is finished being used?

I cannot answer these questions, as it is a point of design. Filtering the array in-place, and providing a facility to handle rejected data addresses some problems, but it is a compromise.

Here is a cursory example:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static size_t filter(
    void *base,
    size_t nel,
    size_t width,
    int (*fn)(void *),
    void (*on_reject)(void *))
{
    size_t len = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nel; i++) {
        void *element = (char *) base + i * width;

        if (fn(element))
            memcpy(((char *) base + len++ * width), element, width);
        else if (on_reject)
            on_reject(element);
    }

    return len;
}

static int is_even(void *el)
{
    int *val = el;

    return *val % 2 == 0;
}

static int is_uppercase(void *el)
{
    const char *val = *((char (*)[32]) el);

    if (!*val)
        return 0;

    while (*val)
        if (!isupper((unsigned char) *val++))
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

static int starts_with_ba(void *el)
{
    return 0 == strncmp(*(char **) el, "ba", 2);
}

static void reject_ba(void *el)
{
    free(*(char **) el);
}

int main(void)
{
    int nums[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
    size_t nums_l = filter(nums, sizeof nums / sizeof *nums, sizeof *nums,
            is_even, NULL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < nums_l; i++)
        printf("%d\n", nums[i]);

    char strs[][32] = {
        "hello",
        "World",
        "UPPER",
        "CASE",
        "no",
        "lower",
        "OKAY"
    };

    size_t strs_l = filter(strs, sizeof strs / sizeof *strs, sizeof *strs,
            is_uppercase, NULL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < strs_l; i++)
        printf("%s\n", strs[i]);

    char *data[] = {
        strdup("foo"),
        strdup("bar"),
        strdup("baz"),
        strdup("qux")
    };

    size_t data_l = filter(data, sizeof data / sizeof *data, sizeof *data,
            starts_with_ba, reject_ba);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < data_l; i++) {
        puts(data[i]);
        free(data[i]);
    }
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
2
4
6
8
UPPER
CASE
OKAY
bar
baz
```

Comment: I have not used qsort yet because I am still learning the basics of programming. Your explanation helped me understand some concepts, but I didn't get all of them. I will review your answer again and try to understand it. Anyways what's this size_t?

Comment: @AqibJavidBhat [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is an *unsigned* type used for indexing memory and storing memory sizes, as it is guaranteed to be large enough to store the maximum size of any object. It is the resulting type of [`sizeof`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean an *array* of strings (as opposed to an array of `char`s), then your "elementSize" is `sizeof(char *)`. Your array of strings is a list of pointers to the strings. A "filter" in this case would accept or reject each string in its entirety.