# passing different structs to a function as void *

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I start by saying that I ain't no C expert and this is probably the first big project I am involved with using this language.

I have this function type

```
typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_args_t)(
  const size_t function, 
  const size_t dimension, 
  const size_t instance, 
  const long rseed,
  const void *args, 
  const char *problem_id_template, 
  const char *problem_name_template);
```

In this basic example, it seems like there would be no need to write a function template, but there actually is cause I need to write wrappers around those functions, which will have as one of their argument a function belonging to this template, but this is not actually relevant for the problem that I was facing

An example of this function is:

```
static coco_problem_t *f_ellipsoid_rotated_bbob_problem_allocate(const size_t function,
                                                                 const size_t dimension,
                                                                 const size_t instance,
                                                                 const long rseed,
                                                                 const void *args,
                                                                 const char *problem_id_template,
                                                                 const char *problem_name_template)
```

While another example is:

```
static coco_problem_t *f_schaffers_bbob_problem_allocate(const size_t function,
                                                         const size_t dimension,
                                                         const size_t instance,
                                                         const long rseed,
                                                         const void *args,
                                                         const char *problem_id_template,
                                                         const char *problem_name_template)
```

There are some more examples, that there is no need to paste here.

The problem is that I have to pass different stuff to each function through the `args` argument.

For representing the extra arguments that I need to pass through the `args` argument, I created some very simple structure, like:

```
typedef struct{
  double conditioning;
} f_ellipsoid_args_t;
```

for the first function and:

```
typedef struct{
  double conditioning;
  double penalty_scale;
} f_schaffers_args_t;
```

Then I call these functions with:

```
    f_schaffers_args_t *args;
    args->conditioning = 1000.0;
    args->penalty_scale = 10.0;
    printf("\nsuite_bbob.c:function=%lu\n", (long unsigned) function);
    printf("suite_bbob.c:args->conditioning=%f\t", args->conditioning);
    printf("suite_bbob.c:args->penalty_scale=%f\n", args->penalty_scale);
    problem = f_schaffers_bbob_problem_allocate(function, dimension, instance, rseed_17, &args,
        problem_id_template, problem_name_template);
```

And, inside of the `f_schaffers_bbob_problem_allocate` function I have:

```
  f_schaffers_args_t *f_schaffers_args;
  f_schaffers_args = ((f_schaffers_args_t *) args);

  printf("f_schaffers.c:f_schaffers_args->conditioning=%f\t", f_schaffers_args->conditioning);
  printf("f_schaffers_args->penalty_scale=%f\n", f_schaffers_args->penalty_scale);
```

But then the resulting output is:

```
suite_bbob.c:function=17
suite_bbob.c:args->conditioning=10.000000   suite_bbob.c:args->penalty_scale=10.000000
f_schaffers.c:f_schaffers_args->conditioning=0.000000   f_schaffers_args->penalty_scale=-0.000000
```

I guess there is a problem with dereferencing and type casting the args pointer inside of `f_schaffers_bbob_problem_allocate`, but I really cannot understand what.

I tried a different "hack" to solve this problem, by creating a structure of structures containing all of these `f_<function_name>_args_t` structures, like:

```
struct f_args_t{
  f_ellipsoid_args_t f_ellipsoid_args;
  f_schaffers_args_t f_schaffers_args;
  /*etc. etc.*/
}
```

and then passing it instead of `void *args`, something like having:

```
typedef coco_problem_t *(*coco_problem_bbob_allocator_args_t)(
  const size_t function, 
  const size_t dimension, 
  const size_t instance, 
  const long rseed,
  const f_args_t *args, 
  const char *problem_id_template, 
  const char *problem_name_template);
```

instead of the signature above.

This solution worked just fine. However, I feel like it's not best practice in some sense because it adds another layer of complexity with the nested structs that I dont feel like it's particularly maintainable. In addition, I also wanted to learn how to use `void*` arguments in this way, which I think could be very useful and powerful (probably won't be, but I'd be curious anyway).

Thanks for the clarifications.

Comment: `f_schaffers_args = (f_schaffers_args_t *) coco_allocate_memory(sizeof(*f_schaffers_args));` followed by
  `f_schaffers_args = ((f_schaffers_args_t *) args);` will leak the allocation you make first. Why is that allocation even made? Why is there dynamic allocation of `f_schaffers_args_t` before the call to the function at all?

Comment: There wasnt before, I put it cause I wanted to try what was gonna happen with that, but the result is the same. Gonna edit the post now, sorry

Comment: Ok this should be the last edit, I recompiled without the memory allocation and this is what I got

Comment: Now you have a `f_schaffers_args_t*` that you start using without it pointing at any memory at all. Why not make an automatic variable? `f_schaffers_args_t args;` ? You send it to the function by taking its address: `&args`. Inside `f_schaffers_bbob_problem_allocate` you don't need to allocate any memory for the arguments. Just make a `f_schaffers_args_t* args` that points at the pointer you've sent in.

Comment: That was actually a great point, now I fixed it. Thank you I was stuck since yesterday I and I couldnt think of the simplest thing :'(... Thank again

Comment: Anyway, is it as I thought that using this solution with void * is better/more elegant than doing the nested struct, or it's nothing to be particularly worried about when writing prod code?

Comment: I don't see any nested structs, but the solution you have now seems rather idiomatic. You send in the data via a `void*` and cast it back to a pointer to the proper type inside the function. It's of course important to make the correct cast everywhere.

Comment: I was referring to the last part of the post. Cool, thank you again

Comment: My answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) may help a bit. It that post I talk a bit about passing `void *` vs. a common struct with a type field and/or vtable pointer.