# Is there a way to hot-reaload the source code of a program during its runtime?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a logic simulation software in C (in Windows btw). I want it to have a feature where you could create a new component struct(XOR gate, ALU's, or entire Turing machine) just by writing a few details about input, output, internal state, and what they do in response to this data. But to use these components I have to define the struct before compilation of the program. This defeats the purpose of the feature which is create template for new component while using the program.

Here is what is came up with:

I implement a subset of C compiler which I care about within C and encapsulate it in a function that can be called during runtime.

But, I think there is a better, or at least, a different way to do it. I feel like it has something to do with dynamically linked libraries, but I have no clue what they are or how to implement them.

Comment: Shared libraries (a.k.a. DLL's)? Rebuild and reload.

Comment: If defining a struct dynamically would be sufficient to address the problem, then certainly so would providing a flexible data structure that can model any component.  With component details as data instead of code, you don't need to do any dynamic compilation.

Comment: But are you sure you *don't* need code to go with your component data?  You wouldn't get that with a struct alone even if you went that route.  And if you need anything but the simplest of code to go with each struct, then defining new components on the fly is suddenly a *much* larger problem.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How would I do that without dynamic compilation if I don't know what the component might look like before compilation. And what would a 'flexible data structure' look like in this case? PS: I forgot to mention, a component takes output from other components as input and processes them and then outputs

Comment: @PrateekBana, even if you did dynamically generate binary plugins, the main program would not know the details of the new components.  They would be isolated in the plugins.  So the question is, what information does your program need to know about each component? Number of inputs?  Number of outputs? Presumably more?  What makes structures for different components different from each other?  What characteristics do they share?

Comment: @JohnBollinger A component structure must contain: array of inputs, array of outputs(input/ouput are numbers in any base), internal state (an array of numbers), functions(function pointers, rather) that get triggered by a paritcular internal state or input, which then change the internal state or the output.

Comment: Maybe you should think about this as a plugin architecture. Each component is fully described in its own shared library (`.dll/.so`) file. They are all in a given component directory. When the program starts up, it does `LoadLibrary` on each file. The base program knows nothing of the components. It only knows to hook up to a given library file. The library init function registers the component via calls back into the main program, adding virtual function tables, etc.

Comment: @CraigEstey I am new to this (but I think this is the type of answer I need). Can you show an example of plugin architecture in C?

Comment: Well, @PrateekBana, what you describe sounds compatible with defining *one* structure type that can support *every* component type.  The main problem is the functions, which I anticipated.  I suggest to you that having to write behavior for your components probably takes the matter out of the realm of "a few details".  Nevertheless, if you want to support that then I suggest using an embedded scripting language, such as Lua, for that.  Then, indeed, component definitions can be entirely data as far as the host C program is concerned, meaning you don't need to compile anything dynamically.

Comment: I would suggest different language like C# for example where you have it almost natively

Comment: @JohnBollinger Don't ask me why, but I want to force a way to do it in C only, in way other than I described in the question (If it is possible at all)

Comment: Come up with a basic domain-specific-language that can be used to describe these structures (Or use an existing format like json or whatever), and write an interpreter for it in C that can process the description into an internal format and use it in running simulations.

Comment: The basic trick is to have a "common" struct for all components that has a type and the VFT. For an example, see my answer: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) This could be adapted. There are examples of plugin arches. Loadable modules in the linux kernel, plugins for PhotoShop, etc.

Comment: Doing things like that is a lot easier in languages like Python and VBScript where there is an exec function that compiles and executes code at runtime.  Does it have to be in C or can you use some other language?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to hot-reaload the source code of a program during its runtime?

1. It is possible for a process to *replace itself* with a a new one built from updated sources.  That will not preserve program state, but you could conceivably export all necessary details of the current state to a file, then have the new instance use that to restore state.
2. On many platforms, it is possible to dynamically load and unload (and reload) plugins.

Generally speaking, however, it is *not* possible to just swap out the binary executable of a running C program such that the program seamlessly continues to run, on the new version.

> I implement a subset of C compiler which I care about within C and encapsulate it in a function that can be called during runtime.

Why in the world would you do that?  Let me be clear: I *hate* the idea of dynamically compiling and integrating new binary components for your program.  But if you're hellbent on doing that, then at least use an existing C compiler.

> But, I think there is a better, or at least, a different way to do it. I feel like it has something to do with dynamically linked libraries, but I have no clue what they are or how to implement them.

The plugin alternative is what you seem to be reaching for there.  Shared / dynamically-linked libraries are among the most common approaches to plugins for programs written in C and other compiled languages.  But that is far too broad a topic to cover in a StackOverflow answer.

Overall, I urge you to avoid approaches that involve the program attempting to self-modify, whether directly or via binary plugins.  If you want to provide for user-defined component types, then they should be defined by *data*, not (C) code.