# How to make a Template Function in C

Tags: c, templates, polymorphism, void-pointers

I'm writing a code for task which contain only two data structure(6 queues and 4 collections). But the problem is that I do not know exactly which data structures I will need until the moment of compilation because i'm configuring information in file. I ask a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78130212/how-to-make-an-instance-in-runtime-c) to solve one of several problem and there was a good solution for me. I use void* and enum for type. And then use switch-case for handling all cases; But then i have a NEW PROBLEM: I don't wanna create six different realisations for each of collection type.

Config file look like:

```
BinomialHeap
HashSet
23:17:57 03/09/24
23:17:57 03/09/24
36 min_time_for_1_request
43 max_time_for_1_request 
52 number_of_department
48 34 36 19 30 19 48 42 49 46 39 18 13 36 49 20 17 23 10 18 48 18 30 11 13 24 42 33 24 21 40 23 45 25 32 24 34 29 17 34 24 47 43 29 34 43 39 43 17 41 12 14
```

1.571111 - overload_coeff

And then created queue and enumerates for data types:

```
typedef enum queue_type {
    BINARY_Q,
    BINOMIAL_Q,
    LEFTIST_Q,
    SKEW_Q,
    FIBONACCI_Q,
    TREAP
} queue_type;

typedef enum collection_type
{
    BST_T,
    VECTOR_T,
    HT_T,
    UNKNOWN_T,
} collection_type;

void QUEUE_FUNC(void *data, const queue_type type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case BINARY_Q:
            printf("BINARY_Q\n");
            break;
        case BINOMIAL_Q:
            printf("BINOMIAL_Q\n");
            break;
        case FIBONACCI_Q:
            printf("FIBONACCI_Q\n");
            break;
        case SKEW_Q:
            printf("SKEW_Q\n");
            break;
        case LEFTIST_Q:
            printf("LEFTIST_Q\n");
            break;
        case TREAP:
            printf("TREAP\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Unknown type\n");
            break;
    }
}
```

Main look like:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    generate_config("out.txt"); // CONFIGURE INFO FILE

    // READ AND PARSE FILE

    size_t q_size = 0;
    queue_type q_type = 0;
    void *queue_data = NULL;

    if (!strcmp(queue_str, "BinaryHeap")) { q_size = sizeof(VECTOR); q_type = BINARY_Q;}
    else if (!strcmp(queue_str, "BinomialHeap")) { q_size = sizeof(HT); q_type = BINOMIAL_Q;}
    else if (!strcmp(queue_str, "FibonacciHeap")) { q_size = sizeof(BST); q_type = FIBONACCI_Q;}
    else if (!strcmp(queue_str, "SkewHeap")) { q_size = sizeof(BST); q_type = SKEW_Q;}
    else if (!strcmp(queue_str, "LeftistHeap")) { q_size = sizeof(BST); q_type = LEFTIST_Q;}
    else if (!strcmp(queue_str, "Treap")) { q_size = sizeof(BST); q_type = TREAP;}


    if (q_size != 0 ) queue_data = malloc(q_size);
    
    QUEUE_FUNC(queue_data, q_type); 
}
```

And If i had a HashSet, i need to store a Queue in HashSet, but i actually don't know HOW. Thank you for reading.

Comment: _I don't wanna create six different realisations for each of collection type"_ But different data structures are implemented differently; you need to write code for each. It's not clear how you expect to solve it even if you had templates.

Comment: It seems like you want to select at *runtime* rather than *compile* time?  In which case you want dynamic polymorphism (generaly implemented with `void *` and enums in C), and not a "template" (which usually means static polymorphism -- resolved at compile time rather than runtime).

Comment: Your impl is similar to the "switch" version within the link I gave in your prior question. The vtable approach is extensible. Once again: [Writing a 'generic' struct-print method in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65621483/5382650) provides a roadmap for your impl. As Ted mentioned, you have to provide impl for each type you define. The vtable approach in my answer is similar to defining a `virtual` function in C++.

Comment: Searching for [dynamic polymorhism in C](https://www.google.com/search?q=dynamic+polymorphins+in+C) brings up a bunch of links, including some [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194250/polymorphism-in-c)

Comment: @TedKleinBergman, If i had a Templates and C++, i'd write my collections(DynamicArr, BST, HashTable, Trie) on templates, and then... Oh, it has a problem cause i have only void* and enum type, and it's not enough for template type... Sorry, my bad...

Comment: @РобертБатоян It might be a misunderstanding, but it seems like you want a different data structure depending on what the configuration file says. Each data structure needs different implementations, and different implementations cannot be written with templates. You might mean that you want to have different data types for the same collection, in which templates can help you. You can do this in C, but it depends on the data types you want to support and what the data structures need to do on each type. If they're primitives, then you can rely on memory layout (`memcmp`, `memcpy`, etc.)